# sfValidator for compare password sha1

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, validation

I would like make login panel based on Symfony/Doctrine validators.

I found somethings:

```
new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password_again')
```

This is in UserForm.class.php

Here password_again is value for input password_again. How can i get this value from database? I have in database password hash with SHA1.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Check a password against the database, or requiring a user to repeat a password a second time when chosing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look on symfony's sfDoctrineGuardPlugin (or sfGuardPlugin if you use Propel ORM), you'll find everything you need.

- A login form
- Password validation
- Groups and privileges
- ....

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to make a login form right ? Do you have two password fields (like 'password' and 'password_again') in this form ?

If not, you shouldn't be using the sfValidatorSchemaCompare.

Answer (score 0):

create two fields password and confirm password

and put this at the end of validations

```
$this->validatorSchema['confirm_password'] = clone
    $this->validatorSchema['password'];
    $this->widgetSchema->moveField('confirm_password', 'after', 'password');
    $this->mergePostValidator(
        new sfValidatorSchemaCompare(
            'password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'confirm_password',
            array(), array('invalid' => 'Password does not match! Please retype')));
```